# Metaheuristic Algorithm vs evolutionary algorithm?

Tags: java

what is the difference between "meta-heuristic" and "evolutionary" algorithm? applications for each, with sample code?

i thought i can use artificial immune system for particular problem how can we frame it based on those algorithm?

Comment: *"applications for each, with sample code?"*  Adding a question mark does not turn that statement into a question.  Note also that SO is not a code generation factory, so if it were reworded as a request to supply code, the answer would typically be 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

meta-heuristic algorithm uses all evolutionary algorithm. Meta-Heuristic is an algorithm chosing the best suitable algorithm at each iteration and applies it.

Comment: To clarify, I would say that genertic algorithm is a type of metaheuristic. Other types include ant colony optimization and iterated local search.